# Dwolla not deleting my account

Tags: user-accounts

Yesterday I started to create an account on Dwolla. As I couldn't input certain required information, I had to cancel the signup.

When I tried to find a "Delete account" option, I notice there's none. That means that **I can still login, by entering my email and password**.

So I sent an email to support asking to (please) delete my account, and this is what I get:

> Our data retention policy is based on the laws applicable to Dwolla. We are required to retain certain customer information even after account closure in order to comply with those laws. Per our policy, we will only retain customer information to allow us to comply with such laws and enforce our TOS. Please be assured that your information is protected and kept secure on our encrypted servers.

Is this right? I can't get them to delete my account, even if I ask them to do so?

Comment: I am. But figured I would also have a try here.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that’s right—as required by the law.

> **Note:** We cannot delete your account entirely*.
>
> * Like all financial services and institutions, Dwolla is required by law to retain customer information for a minimum of five years. The two most applicable regulations are: the Bank Secrecy Act (specifically the Customer Identification Program requirements) and the Treasury Department’s Financial Record keeping Regulations-Section 1020.220. Based on these regulations, we cannot delete accounts due to the [**data retention policy**](https://www.dwolla.com/TOS#data) in our Terms of Service.

[Source](http://help.dwolla.com/customer/portal/articles/1203269-closing-your-dwolla-account).

However, you can deactivate it by going to [this page](http://www.dwolla.com/deactivate).

Comment: That's good start, I would be ok with having my account deactivated. Thing is that you need to complete the signup for deactivating the account, and I can't complete the signup.